# Where to place the scripts

Tags: scripting, continuous-integration, hudson

I have written several scripts for my hudson builds. I have place them in the workspace of the particular job i am working on.

I was hoping to know where the best place to put the scripts. Is somewhere in the file system then best place? What if we move build machines? Does hudson designate a place for scripts?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting them inside your project folder `/hudson/jobs/MyProject` instead of inside the workspace. The workspace could be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use source control? If so you can put them in there and get hudson to pull them from there...

Answer (score 1):

If these scripts are related to a particular project, bundle them with the project. Don't put them somewhere else.

If these scripts are used for more then one project, put them in your source control as a a separate project. Than you can pull them down every time you pull your project. If your scm plugin for hudson does not support configuring two separate sources (like subversion does), then just pull the build script using a command line tool for your scm as your first build step.

Build scripts need to be versioned the same way as you code is versioned.